# Representation of a User in REST

Tags: rest, authentication, restful-architecture

I'm slowly beginning to unerstand REST and theres one thing thats confusing me .

I understand that most of the things in REST is a "resource" . So i was wondering what kind of a resource would we be referring to in the case of a user signup / login ?

Is it `users` ? Then does it mean that a POST on `users` would signup for a new user . If that is the case , then how do i authenticate a user ? a GET on `users` with an encoded password / username pair?

I'm really confused with this.

I may be **COMPLETELY** wrong in my understanding given that i'm just starting to understand REST.

Any help is appreciated !

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of an unusual but common problem for REST. Keep thinking about resources.

When you login you're asking the server to create a session for you to access certain resources. So in this case the resource to create would be a session. So perhaps the url would be **/api/sessions** and a POST to that url with a session object (which could just be an object consisting of a username or password and perhaps the UUID) would create a session. In true REST you'd probably point to a new session at **/api/sessions/{UUID}** but in reality (and for security purposes) you'd probably just register a session cookie.

That's my own personal approach to login forms if I were to implement them myself but I always tend to use [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference.html) for that job so this requirement never really takes much consideration.

Comment: Hmm yes the sessions do make sense. But rest being stateless , confuses me even more. Where is this api-key (lets say) maintained ? with the UI ? So then when a new request is made , lets say to get the list of customers .. is this key sent along with the request so that authentication can be made ?

Comment: Nice answer! Btw. if you are using simple session cookies, then your REST service won't be stateless because it will store client state in a session manager system. Session resources are the only workaround by this problem, but they reduce the cacheability of the responses. If you want to use `no-cache, no-store` anyways, then they are perfect. If you want to use `private` caching, then you have to write a lot more complex caching system...

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something similar and this is the solution I have taken so far. Any suggestions welcome :)

I have `users` exclusively for singup and account modifications.

- `GET /users/{id}` gets a user for the profile page for instance
- `PUT /users` creates a new user with username and password. In reality this should send an email with a link to somewhere that confirms the signup with a GET method.
- `POST /users/{id}` modifies the user (for example change password)
- `DELETE /users/{id}`

For authentication I tend to think that the resource I request is the token or the authentication. I have tried to avoid the word "session" because it is supposed to be anti-RESTful, but if you are just creating the illusion of an actual server-side session for your clients, I guess it is fine.

- `PUT /authentication/` with usename/password returns Set-Cookie with the pair user_id / hashed value. Maybe it should be POST. Not sure
- `DELETE /authentication/{user_id}` just deletes the cookie and the user is signed out. Maybe instead of `user_id` it should be a unique `token_id`.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense. I'm following the same as of now :)

Answer (score 0):

Resources can be created, read, update and deleted using a restful approach, see e.g.:
https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/restful-crud-for-html-methods.html

So if you'd like to administrate you users this would be the restful approach to do so.

If you'd like to authenticate the users which you have in your administration dataset you need
to design or select a restful authentication mechanism see e.g.
http://de.slideshare.net/sullis/oauth-and-rest-web-services
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

For a jumpstart on these issues you might want to check out dropwizard:
http://dropwizard.codahale.com/

Answer (score -2):

A resource may have one URI or many
but One URI will have exactly one Resource

Therefore, When Authenticating a user, you are addressing a user who is already registered
While when registering, you are addressing the user (resource) which is yet to be registered.

All you need is a way to process it to your SERVER.

THIS is an example taken from SUGARCRM REST web services implementation. 
REST is like http requests to your SERVER.

For eg, when implementing REST Web Services. 
Every REST Request is going to same File say

`www.your_domain.com/Rest.php?json={your_json_method:'method',params:'watever'}`

Where in Json is the request you are sending as a parameters

Requesting to authenticate a user
`{method:'SignUp', username:'abc', pass:'pass', confirm_pass:'pass'}`
Requesting to register a user
  `{method:'Login', username:'abc', pass:'pass'}`

by this way you can have as many params as you want

Remember JSON is not necessory to be used. you can use simple get params for your query

Comment: I've never heard of this type of REST ever ! REST is not just sending http requests to the server. Have you read the original [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) by roy? :

Comment: first of all I believe in keep it simple and as i said earlier that JSON is not required and i was just giving you the basic idea read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-sugarcrmrest/index.html it was an example of REST web services in HTTP request.